# Knowledge driven software development - is it possible?

Tags: logic, software-engineering, knowledge-representation

Model driven software development is driven by UML models and OCL expressions, ontology driven software development is driven by ontologies but **is it possible (are there research trends) to introduce knowledge based software development?** E.g. there are quite expressive and extensive logic based knowledge representation frameworks like Cyc/OpenCyc (or closed source CogPrime). Maybe it is possible to extend those frameworks with more formal knowledge in accounting and law domains and use these frameworks for code generation? Are there endeavours and what could be the possible paths forward?